# How to create dynamic "$stop1=$_POST['stop1'];" variable and mysql query for inserting data in a table

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    echo $id;

    $busnumber=$_POST['busnumber'];
    $status=$_POST['status'];
    $startpoint=$_POST['startpoint'];
    $stop1=$_POST['stop1'];
    $stop2=$_POST['stop2'];
}
```

I want to create dynamic `$stop2=$_POST['stop2'];` and mysql query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
   UPDATE fromto 
   SET busNumber='$busnumber', status='$status', startPoint='$startpoint', 
     stop1='$stop1', stop2='$stop2', stop3='$stop3', stop4='$stop4', 
     stop5='$stop5', stop6='$stop6', stop7='$stop7'............... 
   WHERE id=$id
");
```

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $key => $val){$$key = $val}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to evaluate all variables to check which are valid SQL fields. In the most general case you might have POST names and SQL names not alike.

At that point you do not even need to set the variables.

I added an `escape` check because, were someone to send you, say,

```
'; --
```

as the value of `busNumber`, your query would become:

```
UPDATE table SET busNumber=''; --', status=...
```

and since "--" starts a comment, MySQL would see:

```
UPDATE table SET busNumber=''; -- *all the rest ignored*
```

which would then bork the `busNumber` column *in the whole table*. You so don't want this to happen. PDO is a good alternative to `mysql_*` functions that would help prevent such problems.

Anyway, you use `mysql_*`, so:

```
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];

$fields = array( // ALL FIELDS EXCEPT ID
   'status' => 'status',
   ...
);

$update = array();
// Since we're not using PDO we have to do a small check ourselves
foreach($fields as $sql => $post)
{
    if (!isset($_POST[$post]))
        $value = 'NULL';
    else
    {
        // If you want to set the variable:
        // ${$post} = $value;
        // or
        // ${$sql} = $value;

        $value = mysql_real_escape($_POST[$post]);
        if (!is_numeric($value))
            $value = "'$value'";
    }
    $update[] = "$sql = $value";
}

$query = "UPDATE table SET " . implode(',', $update) . " WHERE id=$id";

mysql_query($query);
```

Moreover, it would be probably useful (performance-wise and maintenance-wise) to normalize the schema by removing the `stop*` columns and putting them in another table:

```
CREATE TABLE busStops {
    id_bus    integer,
    active    boolean,
    seq_no    integer,
    name      varchar(200)
};
```

or even

```
CREATE TABLE busStops {
    id        integer not null primary key auto_increment,
    name      varchar(200)
    // other geographical information
};

CREATE TABLE bus_has_stop {
    id_bus    integer,
    id_stop   integer,
    sequenc   integer,
}
```

so that if you e.g. renamed a stop from "Street 1 and Street 2" to "Streets 1-2", the rename would affect automatically all buses with a stop there, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ***[extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)***,  `extract($_POST)` gives all you want.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
  extract($_POST);
  // ...
```

But don't forget escape the user input.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
  extract(array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST));
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$_POST['stop1'] = "xx";
$_POST['stop2'] = "vv";
$_POST['stop3'] = "33v";
$_POST['stop555'] = "55";
$_POST['stop777'] = "77";

$busnumber = $status = $startpoint = $id = 33;

$sql = "UPDATE fromto SET busNumber='$busnumber', status='$status', startPoint='$startpoint'";
$sql .= getStop();
$sql .= "WHERE id=$id";

echo $sql;
```

Output

```
UPDATE fromto SET busNumber='33', status='33', startPoint='33'stop1 = 'xx' ,stop2 = 'vv' ,stop3 = '33v' ,stop555 = '55' ,stop777 = '77' WHERE id=33
```

Function used

```
function getStop() {
    $stop = array_filter($_POST, function ($var) {
        return strpos($var, "stop") == 0;
    });
    array_walk($stop, function (&$var, $key) {
        $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
        $var = $key . " = '$var' ";
    }, $stop);
    return implode(",", $stop);
}
```